# How to import jsx with state variables into another react component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, export, frontend

I have a react component and I want to import a long JSX code into it.  However, the JSX has variables which include this.state.example in it.  How do I import this?

Here's an example:

```
class CompA extends Component {
state={displaying:false}; render(){const {displaying}=this.state; return({x})}
}
```

export this file into the top one?

```
export const x = (
<div>displaying</div>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make x as stateless child component.

```
//x.jsx
export const X = ({displaying})=>(
 <div>{displaying}</div>
)

import {X} from "./x.jsx";
class CompA extends Component {
 state={displaying:false}; 
 render(){
  const {displaying}=this.state; 
  return <X displaying={displaying}/>
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

X should be a "dummy" or functional ( as they are called ) React component:

```
const X = ({displaying}) => (
  <div> {displaying} </div>
);
```

So the external file would be like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const X = ({displaying}) => (
  <div> {displaying} </div>
);

export { X };
```

The X component can be now called normally as any other react component, for example:

```
<X displaying="This is the text displayed" />
```

Now you can import it like this:

```
import { X } from './pathToJSFile'
```

And use it in your component:

```
class CompA extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state.displaying = false;
    }


    render() {
        return( 
            <X displaying={this.state.displaying} /> 
        );
    }
}
```